# PHPUnit + Symfony : Loop when trying to log in

Tags: symfony, phpunit, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to authenticate with a form_login through one test but after submitted the form it redirect to /login.

Symfony : 4.0.4, FOSUserBundle : 2.1.1

Does anynone have a clue ? (credentials and selectButton are ok)

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class CompanyControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function companyDefaultAction_isWorking()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Connexion')->form(array(
            '_username'  => '...',
            '_password'  => '...',
        ));     

        $client->submit($form);

        $crawler = $client->followRedirect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/http_authentication.html ?

Comment: Yes thanks anyway, I was just trying to debug with a simple case

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to define the environment variables for the test environment in phpunit.xml.dist :

```
<env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname" />
```